# How to retrieve data from two tables using join in Simple OData Client?

Tags: mysql, asp.net-mvc, odata, linq-to-dataset

I'm using `mvc application` and `simple OData` to retrieve values from two tables.
created object of ODataClient

ODataClient client = new ODataClient("http://localhost:65556/Dev");

Want to retrieve value from two table like in Sql we simply do like following

```
  select * from [Table1] t1 join [Table2] t2
  on t1.Id = t2.Id 
  where t1.[Title] = 'US'
```

Now In SimpleOdata I do not know about two table operation for one table we can simply do something like following

```
ODataClient client = new ODataClient("http://localhost:64576/Dev");  

var packages = await client
                .For<Table1>()
                .Filter(x => x.Title == "US")
                .FindEntriesAsync();
            foreach (var package in packages)
            {
                return package.Title;
            }
            return "test";
```

How can I correct above expression for two tables?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
ODataClient client = new ODataClient("http://localhost:64576/Dev");  

var packages = await client
.For<Table1>()
.Expand(x => x. Table2)
.Filter(x => x.Title == "US")
.FindEntriesAsync();

foreach (var package in packages)
{
     return package.Title;
}
return "test";
```

Comment: It is always recommended to add some explanation to your code

Answer (score 1):

I suppose you should use expand function. Look here http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/odata-support-in-aspnet-web-api/using-$select,-$expand,-and-$value

Comment: true but i want to use client and then make the query as i did it for single object in question `Table1`

Comment: @ashu Recently i used this code and it worked fine             
            Uri uri = new Uri("http://XXX/odata/");
            var container = new Container(uri);
            var allProducts = container.Products.Expand<Supplier>(p => p.Supplier).ToList();